# Expresso:Store - Undefined Property on checkout

Tags: expresso-store, email, error

I've just doing some final tests before go live and when I complete at the checkout I receive the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered    
Severity: Notice    
Message: Undefined property: EE::$template    
Filename: libraries/store_emails.php    
Line Number: 68    
Fatal error: Call to a member function parse_variables() on a non-object in ~/expressionengine/third_party/store/libraries/store_emails.php on line 68
```

The order completes - as far as to say it's in the CP orders page, but clearly the email function is failing and preventing usual redirect.

All other emails (HTML / Plain Text) work fine, the email debug passes.

I've replaced the default email template with simply {order_id} and again with just 'test' to rule out any conditions - and I still get the same error.

EE - **2.5.5** / Store -  **1.6.2** / Payment Gateway - **None**

Comment: That basically means the template library isn't loaded. Are you by any chance calling `store_emails->parse_email()` from your own code somewhere? Otherwise I can't see any reason why the template library wouldn't be loaded, especially if you are placing orders through the front end.

Comment: Oh you mean that custom extension we wrote that syncs the order information with FileMaker when the order completes? Yeah that'll be it... thanks for the fresh eyes Adrian. 

Issue resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian was right... forgot to check our custom module we built that hooks into the checkout process. We corrected the template lib and all is well.

Changed -

```
 $email['subject'] = $this->EE->template->parse_variables($email['subject'], $tag_vars);
```

to

```
 $email['subject'] = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($email['subject'], $tag_vars);
```

As I say, this was a custom module, not Store - so nothing amiss with exp:resso